# int.ToString like HH formatted of DateTime

Tags: c#, .net

```
("dd/MM/yyyy HH")+ " - " + (x.Hour+1).ToString();
```

So here is example

what I got and what I need :

```
0  --->   00 
3  --->   03 
12 --->   12
```

How can I use ToString for it ?

I've tried :

```
x.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH") + " - " + x.AddHours(1).ToString("HH");
```

doesn't works ...

Comment: You want convert int to string or DateTime to string?

Comment: It is unclear what you want, please edit question.

Comment: Give a clear example of your *exact* input (e.g. DateTime instance, or plain int) and an example of your *exact* desired output, e.g. a string like the following: "15/03/2010 09".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just need to make int.ToString having sum leading zeros you can do it like this:

```
    int integer = 5;
    string str = integer.ToString("00"); // str has "05".
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that x is a valid DateTime, this example works (9am appears as "09").

```
        DateTime x = DateTime.Now;

        string hours = x.AddHours(1).ToString("HH");
```

Comment: yes >_< I've tried x.AddHours(1).Hour.ToString("HH"); thank you